# Can I announce my free clipart library on this site?

Tags: support, advertising

We are cartographers from the Caribbean, and we’ve created a free library (clipart) of different vector maps: street city plans and also printable maps of just all countries.

Can I post a link here, or there are some more appropriate place in this forum?

Comment: I'm going to suggest you have a look at the [help] and more particularly [what's on topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Also helpful: [How not to be a spammer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Answer (score 6):

> Can I post a link here, or there are some more appropriate place in this forum?

This is not a classical forum, this is a question-and-answer site. It is not intended as a platform for announcements and similar. Posts that primarily exist for self-promotion [will be deleted very quickly](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). So, no you cannot spread the word about your library here.

What you can do is to ask for strategies **how** to let people know about your library. If you do so, please elaborate what audience you are aiming at, how much energy you are willing to invest, and what you already know and tried.

Comment: about your second paragraph: isn't that internet marketing rather than graphic design? *ponders*

Comment: Why can’t it be both? Marketing your services or products (or free software) is a skill of the graphic designer’s trade and thus I would consider it on-topic here for the same reason that maintaining client relations, determining your prices, etc. are

Comment: That is provided that the *intent* of the question would be to learn those skills, and not a sneaky way to post a spam link anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

No, that'd be spam.